# how to disable html input fields and buttons using jquery

Tags: jquery, disabled-input

I am having trouble disabling a button. What I am trying to do is to disable the button unless typing some words in the input. The following is my code.

```
$('.btn.btn-default').click(function(){
    var post = $('input:text').val();
    $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
    $('input:text').val("");
    $('.count').text('100');
    $('.btn.btn-default').addClass('disabled');
    });


$('input:text').keyup(function(){
    var postLength = (this).val().length;
    var charactersLeft = 100 - postLength;
    $('.count').text(charactersLeft);   
    if (charactersLeft < 0){
    $('.btn.btn-default').addClass('disabled');
    }
    else if (charactersLeft == 100){
        $('.btn.btn-default').addClass('disabled'); 
    }
    else{
        $('.btn.btn-default').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});

$('.btn.btn-default').addClass('disabled');

};
```

The following is my HTML

```
<div class= "blank">
    <input type="text" id="form-control" placeholder="Please Leave Comment Here."/>
    </div>


    <div class = "status">
    <div class= "count">100</div>
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Post">
    </div>

    <ul class="posts">
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you give us a Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YuanHuang/zx48zb7a/

Comment: Just adding a  `disabled` class doesn't automatically disable it. You need to use Bootstrap  to do that.

Comment: Try adding this to the `<head>` section of your page: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: @Abraar Arique Thanks. I got it. I can either set the property or use bootstrap. both work.

Answer (score 6):

TYPO:

```
(this).val().length;
^^^
```

Add the missing `$`. You should be an error in your console pointing out that *"val is not a function"*.

Also adding a class does not disable a button. You need to set the property.

```
$(".btn.btn-default").prop('disabled', true);
$(".btn.btn-default").prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: hi , thanks for the typo correction. the thing is that the button is not disabled. I don't know why. I did not type in anything in the input, and I can still click the Post button.

Comment: Adding a class does not disable a button!

Comment: wow. It works. Thanks so much for the help.